# Why after jquery ajax post (with a link as event) that link doesnt work a 2nd time?

Tags: jquery, post

That is my problem.

I started a fresh solution to get clean code and find out what the problem could be.

There is a simple table with 10 users, all of them haves a 'delete' link that calls a jQuery function. That jQuery function deletes the user and then refreshes the div that contains a table with remaining users.

It works fine except that when you want to use the link for a 2nd time, it doesn't do anything.

Here is all the code you need, you can recreate situation with a fresh "MVC4" Basic visual studio solution.

---

first of all, I am using "cdn" to get "json" scripts from here :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

This is my "Index.cshtml" page :

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".PruebaPost").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var values = {
                id: this.id
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("BorrarUsuario","Principal")",
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                    $("#TodosLosUsuarios").html(
                           $.get('@Url.Action("IndexPartial")',{}, function(data) { 
                               $("#TodosLosUsuarios").html(data);
                           })
                    );
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                    $("#TodosLosUsuarios").html('There is error while submit');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
<div>my header that must not change: @DateTime.Now.ToString()</div>

    <div id="TodosLosUsuarios">
        @Html.Partial("IndexPartial")
    </div>
<div>this is a footer, that will never be replaced</div>
```

---

This is the code inside "IndexPartial.cshtml" :

```
@model WebParaPrubeas.Models.CoolUsersModel

<table>

    <tr>
        <td><b>IdCoolUser</b></td>
        <td><b>LastName</b></td>
        <td><b>FirstName</b></td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.CoolUsers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.IdCoolUser</td>
            <td>@item.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.FirstName</td>

            <td><a href="#" class="PruebaPost" id="@item.IdCoolUser">Erase!</a></td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

---

this is my model code :

```
namespace WebParaPrubeas.Models
{
    public class CoolUsersModel
    {
        public List<CoolUser> CoolUsers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoolUser {

        public Int32 IdCoolUser { get; set; }

        public String LastName { get; set; }

        public String FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

And this is my controller, with a simple test repository saved on Session, just for test purposes, it will be called only the first time if session is null.

```
public class PrincipalController : Controller
{

    public static List<CoolUser> ObtenerUsuarios()
    {
        var resultado = new List<CoolUser>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            resultado.Add(new CoolUser
            {
                IdCoolUser = i,
                LastName = "LastName " + i.ToString(),
                FirstName = "FirstName " + i.ToString()
            });

        }
        return resultado;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usuarios = (List<CoolUser>)Session["CoolUsers"];

        if (usuarios == null)
        {
            usuarios = ObtenerUsuarios();
            Session.Add("CoolUsers", usuarios);
        }

        var modelo = new CoolUsersModel { CoolUsers = usuarios };

        return View(modelo);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult IndexPartial()
    {
        var usuarios = (List<CoolUser>)Session["CoolUsers"];

        var modelo = new CoolUsersModel { CoolUsers = usuarios };

        return PartialView(modelo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BorrarUsuario(Int32 id)
    {
        var usuarios = (List<CoolUser>)Session["CoolUsers"];

        var eliminar = usuarios.Single(s => s.IdCoolUser == id);

        usuarios.Remove(eliminar);

        Session["CoolUsers"] = usuarios;

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

}
```

---

As I said before, you can test this problem by erasing any user, page will refresh with new version of users (without the erased one) but the links that perform erase of users will not be working any more.

Anybody haves a solution for this? :(

thanks!

Comment: is the ´alert("success");´ showing the second time you click the link ?

Comment: Did you try @Rashmin Javiya solution ?

Comment: No, on the second time, the alert is not executing, In fact it doesn´t execute any javascript code at all. It works fine the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind you click handler using `on` method.

```
$("#TodosLosUsuarios").on("click", ".PruebaPost", function(){
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: The problem is not my bind method, the way Im binding the click event is working fine the first time, only fails the seccond time.

Comment: @Yogurtu The reason behind not calling event second time is it replace the original DOM element in ajax callback function. so click handler will not find that exact DOM elemt it was bind with and not call event again. did you tried as i mentioned?

Comment: Indeed, your solution is the right one. But I might add that your explanation is not the only one reasson cause it doesn't work, also my bind method is called in a deprecated way... (didn't know that).. that method doesn't find the exact dom element (your explanation)... thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Try this might this work

```
$("#TodosLosUsuarios .PruebaPost").click(function(){
// code here
});
```

Comment: The problem is not my bind method, the way Im binding the click event is working fine the first time, only fails the seccond time.